# struts2 property value as argument of javascript function

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have one  in jsp page.

i want to pass this value as argument of java script function call

my jsp apge code is:

```
  <input type="submit" onclick="play(<s:property value="vname"/>)">
```

my java script function code:

```
  function play(n)
    {
        alert(n);

    }
```

please help me to solve this problem;

regard

Rohit kachhadiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap struts tags with quotes:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="play('<s:property value="vname"/>')">
```

otherwise the value of "vname" will be interpreted as a JavaScript variable, not a string!

Answer (score 1):

Using struts2 tag:

```
<s:submit onclick="javascript:play('%{vname}')" />
```

Comment: In Struts2 you can pass a property without specifying the property tag. I suppose that vname is a variable in his action. I tried it and works in my case.

Comment: In my struts jsp I have this:     <s:submit onclick="javascript:play('%{vname}')" />

Comment: There is a huge difference between your answer and your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with daveoncode, apart from that 
In your js, get it directly like

```
var varName = document.forms[0].name/id.value;
```

Or you have one more option to write inline js and pass value of your element. But its a bad practice.